# What does byte-perfect consistency mean (serialization)?

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, bson

I was reading the Design Rationale from the Ethereum project. When reading through the section on RLP (the serialization format they use) I cannot understand the following statement about why they didn't use Protobuf or BSON.

Source : [Ethereum design rationale](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale)

> The alternative to RLP would have been using an existing algorithm such as protobuf or BSON; however, we prefer RLP because of (1) simplicity of implementation, and (2) guaranteed absolute byte-perfect consistency.

Specifically, the second point about byte-perfect consistency. From the paragraph I infer that BSON and Protobuf are not "byte-perfect" consistent.

My question is what does this mean ?

Comment: Ask them. Off topic.

Answer (score 3):

The next sentence is probably the key:

> Key/value maps in many languages don't have an explicit ordering, and floating point formats have many special cases, potentially leading to the same data leading to different encodings and thus different hashes.

I don't know about BSON, but I can confirm that in protobuf the same data can be represented in multiple different byte sequences. Although *usually* serializers will all produce the same output from the same data, it is not a formal guarantee, so you can't just glance at two outputs (or their hashes) and conclude "if the bytes are the same the data is the same, otherwise the data is different". The first part is true (as long as you're using the same  schema definition each time), but the second part ("otherwise") is incorrect. It sounds like they wanted that ability. Specifically, they wanted "input X always has output Y and can **only** have output Y".